# RAILS - How to write a query that gets records created within 1 minute of each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and am unsure how to write a query that gets records created within 1 minute of each other. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: read all the records sorted by created_at, loop through them comparing the created_at values and if they are within 1 minute then add them to an array of records. When you are done you will have an array of records that are all within a minute of the record next to it

Comment: (1) Which database? (2) What specifically do you mean by "created within 1 minute of each other"? Are you trying to group rows? Could one row be in multiple groups? Maybe include some sample data and tell us which ones you'd find and why you'd find those.

Comment: 1) SQLite 2) Yes I am trying to group rows. I am trying to group rows that have the same name and were created 1 minute apart.

Comment: @vik what do you mean by "group"? Are you looking to have both rows returned in an Array of Arrays or a Key/Value pair (if so what is the key) or are you looking to aggregate some value? What happens if there are 3 records like `['2021-10-22 12:00:00','2021-10-22 12:00:45','2021-10-22 12:01:20']` what does the grouping look like here because the central value is within 1 minute of each of the outer values however the outer values are greater than 1 minute apart. Please provide input and desired output examples preferably including a case as described.

Comment: @engineersmnky in your example all of the records should be returned in an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query:

```
User.where(updated_at: (Time.now - 1.minutes)..Time.now)
```

In this query, you can pass time manually if you want to find records from the last 24 hours then you can use like this:

```
User.where(updated_at: (Time.now - 24.hours)..Time.now)
```